# Retrieve within Cookies from C# to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

Hello guys I have this problem of getting `lastGuestInsertedId` from C# cookies in a code behind file  to another web form that retrieve `lastGuestInsertedId` values by jquery and then show the value by alerting. Any ideas?

C# codes

```
            HttpCookie GuestCookie = new HttpCookie("GuestCookie");
            GuestCookie["Key"] = Convert.ToString(lastGuestInsertedId) ;

            GuestCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
            Response.Cookies.Add(GuestCookie);
```

JQuery codes

```
            var guestkey = $.cookie("GuestCookie")
            alert(guestkey);
```

Comment: @Tassadaque the problem is that i need to retrieve the value which is by C# is  if (Request.Cookies["GuestCookie"]["Key"] != null)
                { GuestKey = Request.Cookies["GuestCookie"]["Key"];

Comment: so what is the jquery way of doing it

Comment: $.cookie is the right way of setting cookies on jQuery, but i think I  need more info.... Do you want to set a cookie on the client side or on asp.net?

Comment: err i am setting cookie on the client side to show the value that will be carry over

Answer (score 2):

`$.cookie` is not part of default jQuery. You need some jQuery plugin to do that.

To check if you actually have cookies on client side - `alert(document.cookie)`.

Comment: well i stored the value in C# codes then i need to show whether the value was carry over to the other forms by using client side

Comment: BTW i do have this too  <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: More suggestions: Use Fiddler (or other HTTP debugger) to see what is actually send to the browser; see if your cookies are blocked; see if script sees anything useful with typing `javascript:alert(document.cookie)` in address bar...

Comment: Actually the forms are all linked by cookies